# Cant find server logs on tomcat | Unable to login after deployment aws ec2

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I am trying to deploy springboot application on aws ec2 . I installed tomcat and java on this instance. My jenkins job says build and deploy successful and I find my war file on tomcat webapps folder.

And also i dont find tomcat serverlogs on this ec2.

But when I open the url. I am facing this error.

HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message /login

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Any suggestions?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzXTT.png)

**updated info:** I have uploaded a springboot jar file using wget command.  And running jar file using command java -jar filename.jar on aws ec2 instance.

And I saw this error message: Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile spring-boot-web-thymeleaf-1.0.jar. Please see Springboot app error image. Please refer to the screenshots attached.

Note  : I tried running in local system and it worked fine without issues.

My jar file link - https://github.com/vmarlabalraj/springboot/blob/master/spring-boot-web-thymeleaf/target/spring-boot-web-thymeleaf-1.0.jar

[Springboot app error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5uVy.png)
**strong text**

Edited 05/01

I checked my local and aws java versions are same which is 1.8. This jar file is springboot jarfile which has a inbuilt tomcatserver. So i didnt install tomcat  on aws.Please refer to the screenshots attached.

[**Springboot running on local screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvnTZ.png)

[Springboot  running on aws screenshot**strong text**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmYwL.png)

Comment: You'll have to post more details on what happened during deployment and also the before/after of the EC2. And where are you not able to login? Tomcat Console?

Comment: @saurabh14292 Thankyou for looking into my post. I have updated the info along with the screenshot. Please let me know if you need anymore details.

Comment: Let's breakdown the entire picture into smaller ones to rule out possibilities:
EC2 : Are you able to ping, login, navigate directory structure? If yes, then it looks good.
Tomcat : Are you able to run tomcat stand-alone? Without any jar/war? Is it starting? Is it accessible with IP:Port? If yes, then no issues here.
Springboot jar : Have you compared the jar on EC2 against your local? Checksum, size, java version to run etc?

Comment: @saurabh14292 I have updated the main post along with the screenshot. Please let me know if you need anymore details.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, I downloaded your jar from github on EC2 and executed java -jar  command.

Although JDK version was 11, because of Amazon Linux2 AMI, I could see jar getting executed.

I downloaded the jar using below command :

```
curl -o spring-boot-web-thymeleaf-1.0.jar https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vmarlabalraj/springboot/master/spring-boot-web-thymeleaf/target/spring-boot-web-thymeleaf-1.0.jar
```

Please check if you are downloading the jar correctly or not as you o/p shows it is corrupted. Jar on github is not corrupted.

Also, the issue is with downloaded jar, and not with EC2 or tomcat.